# Duplicates with LEFT JOIN on historical roster

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table where I have employee data by week... Let's say I just have 3 employees. I need to track their information weekly, because we might change their supervisor in any week and employee performance will also count towards supervisor performance

| week | employeeId | employeeName | supervisor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-10 | 1 | David | Bob |
| 2022-07-10 | 2 | Joe | Bob |
| 2022-07-10 | 3 | Miriam | Martin |
| 2022-07-17 | 1 | David | Bob |
| 2022-07-17 | 2 | Joe | Bob |
| 2022-07-17 | 3 | Miriam | Martin |

I have another table, where I track sales, I just have the employeeId showing to that table.

| week | employeeId | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-10 | 1 | $500 |
| 2022-07-10 | 2 | $400 |
| 2022-07-10 | 3 | $309 |

I want to create a new table that show how's their supervisor with left join

```
FROM company.sales AS t    
LEFT JOIN company.employee_roster AS roster
  ON
    roster.week = t.week
    AND roster.employeeId = t.employeeId
```

But I always get duplicated data... If I remove the JOIN statement, I get the data as intended without the supervisor's name.

Is the above approach the right one? Is there any better  way to join those tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
SELECT *
FROM `company.sales` AS t    
LEFT JOIN `company.employee_roster` AS roster
USING(week, employeeId)
```

with output

[image]

or just use below (this cover scenario when columns to be joined can have different names)

```
SELECT t.*, employeeName, supervisor
FROM `company.sales` AS t    
LEFT JOIN `company.employee_roster` AS roster
ON t.week = roster.week
AND t.employeeId = roster.employeeId
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try it. just a question, the code above works when, in both tables, the columns have the same name, what happens when some other tables identify `employeeId` as `salesEmployeeId` the same information?

Comment: see addition in answer

Comment: I tried it in both ways, but I still get duplicates. Even without selecting columns from the second table, just by using the `LEFT JOIN` statement, they duplicate

Comment: so, looks like you are missing something important in your data sample - as you can see based on sample in your data  - there is no duplications!

Comment: I copied the roster into a spreadsheet and I filtered the results (only week and employeeId) and I only got one... do you have any insights on how to debug it in bigquery